# Redirect all the versions of website to direct one .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all the versions of my website to direct one. For example I have a domain example.com and it display the same content in many versions like:

```
ww.w.example.com,
w.example.com,
m.example.com,
anystring.example.com,
and many others...
```

I found solution how to redirect www to non www version, but still it isn't resolving my problem.

```
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]    

     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]  
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I edit this code to achieve redirections from any version of my website to http://example.com?

Comment: You have to have wildcard DNS matching in your nameserver setup. If *.example.com    is setup in the DNS server then you have to modify your VHOST entry in the HTTPD configuration file   to be *.example.com  and it will work without any changes to htaccess

Comment: the <somename>.example.com  is whats called a **subdomain**  and is created  via the _DNS zone_ for _example.com_, and not from within the htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```